# Clojure design philosophy of functions vs methods

Tags: clojure, reusability

It's often quoted that

> "It is better to have 100 functions operate on one data structure than 10 functions on 10 data structures." — Alan Perlis

and this is something that is heavily observed in Clojure & it's libraries too e.g

In the [gist](https://gist.github.com/reborg/dc8b0c96c397a56668905e2767fd697f) here, Rich has explained the design principle of `clojure.xml` where once the XML file is read, it is converted to a map and then you have all the functions available to manipulate these maps however you need and that you can reuse these functions with other maps

I'm having trouble understanding how these functions implemented to manipulate maps representing XML's to be used anywhere else?

I mean wouldn't the 100 functions I would've written be specific to the XML domain (i.e. specific to the map schema for XML), so the only reuse of these fn's would be if the map adheres to the same schema

Am I missing anything?

Comment: in my understanding ,for example you can filter out a list of maps with certain field met certain criteria . The very filter function can be used in maps originated from XML also can be used in other context like filtering data in Array of JSON.etc.  Core functions shouldn't focus of `form` of data that user operate on ,but the built in data structure representing the core business logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [linked gist](https://gist.github.com/reborg/dc8b0c96c397a56668905e2767fd697f):

> Look at the way `clojure.xml` processes XML - it deals with an external entity, a SAX parser fronting some XML source, gets the data out of it and into a map, and it's done. There aren't and won't be many more functions specific to XML. The world of functions for manipulating maps will now apply. And if it becomes necessary to have more XQuery-like capabilities in order to handle XML applications, they will be built for maps generally, and be available and reusable on all maps. Contrast this with your typical XML DOM, a huge collection of functions useful nowhere else.

#### Wouldn't the 100 functions I would've written be specific to the XML domain?

No.

Because you would not be dealing with XML anymore.  XML is merely a markup language.  In other language ecosystems (say, Java) when someone refers to XML, it means the markup language AND (almost always) it's extensions and the tools built around them.  The way Clojure (at least `clojure.xml`) handles XML is to read the data and then continue processing it in Clojure's native maps.

---

It is worth noting (as of now) [`clojure.xml`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.xml-api.html) contains only one function, `parse`.  This means it does not support serializing to XML, neither does it support in-place editing of XML data elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing XML with the particular instance of an XML file.

Given a specific XML file like say:

```
<xml>
<node1>One</node1>
<node2>Two</node1>
<node3>
  <node31>
    ThreeOne
  </node31>
  <node32>
    ThreeTwo
  </node31>
</node1>
</xml>
```

It is true that for example, you might want to have logic that grabs the values form the child nodes under `node3`. And so maybe you'd have a function called `get-three-node-child-values`. That function would not be reusable given another XML with a different structure that did not have a node3 with children as the above XML does.

But this is not the functions Rich is talking about being reused. The functions being reused are the ones that you use to implement the logic of `get-three-node-child-values`. Because if what you had was an XML Object, that XML Object would need to have a method to get the node3, and another method to get children of that node, and another method to get the value of that node. All these methods only work for the XML Class of objects, and had to be written for that. But if you turn the XML into a Map, you don't need these methods at all, and don't need to implement them. Since a Map already has methods to navigate and loop over its nodes.

Hope that made it more clear.